# Global mutable state of client-side applications

Tags: javascript, dom, client-side

This is probably a very generic (and maybe naive) question.

As I understand, the programming model of a "client-side" application (i.e. an application that runs in the browser) implies that there is a single shared mutable object -- DOM of the web page -- to be updated by the javascript program. *Naive* applications I have seen consists of dozens JS callbacks that update one large shared DOM,

Is it correct ? How do modern JS frameworks manage it ? How do they implement *data hiding* ?

Comment: _"implies that there is a single shared mutable object -- DOM of the web page"_ - Why does it imply that?

Comment: @nnnnnn I hope I am wrong. That's what I've seen at work. SPAs (Single Page Applications) consist of hundreds JS callbacks that update one huge global DOM and one huge "model".

Comment: Given that you mentioned MVC, wouldn't the DOM be the _view?_ There are frameworks that treat it as such.

Comment: Yes, I think the DOM is the "view". Could you explain in a few words how the modern framework handle this DOM _in principle_ ?

Comment: In a few words? Probably not. The only modern JS framework I've used lately is [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) - the general principle of which being that your html only includes bindings back to your JS-based model, and your client code mostly just interacts with the model (leaving it to Knockout itself to update the view as required).

Comment: Thanks. The applications I am talking about do not use any "modern" framework. They use only `jQuery`. Maybe that's why they use one large mutable DOM.

Comment: Well jQuery isn't a framework, so...

Comment: @Michael In addition to my answer. An application can be structured just as I described without using any third-party frameworks. Have a look at http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript, it will help understanding the core concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you rely on `window.open`, iframes, or allow your application to span multiple inter-communicating windows/tabs (perhaps cmmunication through `postMessage`), you have no other choice to manipulate the same document: there's only one document.

However, it's not because a single document is manipulated that the document itself can't be divided into multiple encapsulated collaborating modules. Nicholas Zakas exposes this concept very well in his [Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw) presentation.

A module should be given a very strict portion of the document on which they operates. That's their own little sandbox and they shouldn't reach into other module's sandbox. If they need to communicate, they do it in a very decoupled way (e.g. through a [Mediator](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)).

Most today's frameworks rely on client-side variations of Model-View-Controller (MVC), often referred to as MV*/MVW, to achieve that goal. I will not go in details here, but the main goal is to decouple the data from the view (presentation), as well as often decoupling the view from the handling of user actions which is done in a Controller object.

Until very recently, there was no real way to enforce encapsulation. For exemple, it wasn't possible to prevent some code external to a jQuery plugin to modify the DOM structure generated by that plugin. We had to rely on programmer's professionnalism to ensure they did not reach into a plugin's internals.

Now, with the [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/) specification which introduces new concepts such as [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), real encapsulation will be able to take place. Unfortunately, the specification is not yet implemented in browsers, but luckily for us, there's Google's [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) project, which can be seen as a Web Components shim.

Answer (score 1):

Modern JS frameworks use the Javascript language to:

1. register interest in DOM events
2. respond to DOM events:

   - either directly by creating or mutating object state, or
   - by making remote "ajax" requests and using the response to update their state
3. Reflect some or all of their modified state by (selectively) updating the DOM.

And thats it. thats the basic run-loop of a modern client application.

There are many frameworks you can use to do this of course and each of them implement the basic paradigm differently. Some frameworks like jQuery tend to take a "DOM is truth" approach and hang their state data off the DOM, whilst others like Ember.js are at the opposite end and take a "model is the truth" approach and manage state outside of the DOM.

A common pattern used in many frameworks is MV*, ie Model/View/Something. Frameworks will have some kind of model to manage state, and some kind of view/templating layer, and something else to control/coordinate/orchestrate the application. This could be ad-hoc to non-existent (ie hundreds of DOM event callbacks) or quite structured and sophisticated depending on the framework.

One point worth making since there are some slightly misleading comments, is that the view layer in these frameworks is not equivalent to the DOM. What ends up in the DOM is actually the output of rendering a view, ie the DOM is *the rendition* of a view.